# Is there a way to save many values in one variable using a for-Loop in Robot framework?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, text, robotframework

I need to collect every text witch is in a span element
but the loop overwrite the items...

```
*** Variables ***
${items}    ${EMPTY}

*** Test Cases ***
...

FOR    ${i_i}    IN RANGE    ${Items_Count}
        ${i}=    Evaluate    ${i_i}+1
        ${items[i_i]}=    Get Text    //body[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr/span[${i}]
END
```

...

it should look like this:

```
${items} = {txt1 | txt2 | txt3 | ... | textN}
```

but my result is:

```
${items} = {last text from span-element}
```

Comment: I never used `Robot Framework` but with Google I found [Collections](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) in Robot Framework which shows `Create List` and `Append To List`

Comment: Yes but there must be a way to do it with tuple...

Comment: what tuple? I don't see any tuple. Do you mean add value to tuple? You can't add new value to tuple - tuple is immutable. Do you mean add tuple to `items`? It still may need to create list `items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a list of values:

```
@{list}   Create List
Append To List   ${list}   value_to_append
```

If you want a Dict-like of values:

```
&{dictionary}   Create Dictionary
Set To Dictionary   ${dictionary}   key   value
```